# Form only recognizes one Groupbox property

Tags: c#, forms, groupbox

I am trying to populate a run-time created Form.

First I create my text-properties that's supposed to each button

```
public static List<string> GetDialogs()
    {
        dialogs = new List<string>();
        var tempString = "";

        for (int i = 1; i <= FormSize.getHorizontalButtonCount(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= FormSize.getVerticalButtonCount(); j++)
            {
                //fx 
                tempString = $"{i}x{j*multiplier}";
                dialogs.Add(tempString);
            }

        }

        return dialogs;
    }
```

and my list ends up like "1x5", "1x10", "1x15", "2x5" etc

Then I create all my Radiobuttons

```
public static List<RadioButton> CreateRadioButtons()
    {
        List<RadioButton> radioButtons = new List<RadioButton>();
        for (int i = 0; i < FormSize.getRadioButtonCount(); i++)
        {
            var tempName = $"btn{i}";
            radioButtons.Add(new RadioButton());
            radioButtons[i].Name = tempName;
        }

        return radioButtons;
    }
```

Which just creates a lot of buttons with some names like btn1 etc

Then I populate my Radiobutton-list with my dialog-list

```
private List<RadioButton> PopulateRadiobuttons()
    {
        dialogs = FormDialogs.GetDialogs();
        List<RadioButton> tempRadioButtons = RadioButtonCreator.CreateRadioButtons();
        for (int i = 0; i < FormSize.getRadioButtonCount(); i++)
        {
            tempRadioButtons[i].Text = dialogs[i];
        }

        return tempRadioButtons;
    }
```

Now my Radiobuttons both contain a name like btn20 and a text like 4x30

Then I first populate a GroupBox with all my RadioButton elements before lastly populating my form with the groupbox.

```
public Form PopulateForm()
    {
        _box = new GroupBox();
        radioButtons = PopulateRadiobuttons();
        for (int i = 0; i < radioButtons.Count; i++)
        {
            _box.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);
        }

        _form.Controls.Add(_box);

        return _form;

    }
```

Besides all this, when I call this method to create a form it's only the first radiobutton that appears, the 1x5 one.

How could I go on about including all my buttons in my Form?

Here's what I do so far

```
    private void Bt1_Click(object sender, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        FormCreator fm = new FormCreator();
        f1 = fm.PopulateForm();
        f1.Show();
    }
```

Comment: You are creating only in group box. Also all the radiobuttons will positioned at the same location in the group box. So you are able to see only the top most radio button. If the group box size is small then you can not see the radio buttons if they are positioned out side of the group box size

Comment: So you need to have form and group box big enough to accommodate all the radio buttons and you also need to set location property of radio buttons to different values.

Comment: Automatic positioning is only happening in FlowLayoutPanels.